# merging loop produces and giving a name

Tags: python, numpy

```
import numpy as np
A=([ 3.,1.],  [1.,4.],  [1.,0.], [2., 1.])
for i in A:
   y=i*1
   print y
```

This python loop produces four lists as shown:

```
[3.0, 1.0]
[1.0, 4.0]
[1.0, 0.0]
[2.0, 1.0]
```

But it should be as shown below, other words it should be a matrix. How can it be like that? My second question is how can I give a name to this matrix ?

For example A, B or x something like this

```
  ([[3.0, 1.0]
    [1.0, 4.0]
    [1.0, 0.0]
    [2.0, 1.0]])
```

and

```
A=([[3.0, 1.0]
    [1.0, 4.0]
    [1.0, 0.0]
    [2.0, 1.0]])
```

Comment: `print` is a function which displays the argument to the console. So you are displaying one line at a time to the console. CoryKramer's answer is what you need. Try `A = np.array([[ 3.,1.],  [1.,4.],  [1.,0.], [2., 1.]]); print(A)`. If you have a tuple of lists, like you already have, try: `A = (...)` then `temp = []` then `for row in A: temp.append(transform(row)` then `B = np.array(temp); print(B)`. However, the root of you problem seems to be that you're not actually using numpy arrays.

Answer (score 4):

When you write this line, you simply have a tuple, which has 4 `list` elements.

```
A = ([ 3.,1.],  [1.,4.],  [1.,0.], [2., 1.])
```

If you want to make a `numpy.matrix`, then you can use that to initialize `A`

```
import numpy as np
A = np.matrix([[ 3.,1.],  [1.,4.],  [1.,0.], [2., 1.]])
```

So `A` is now

```
>>> A
matrix([[ 3.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  4.],
        [ 1.,  0.],
        [ 2.,  1.]])
```

Comment: I don't quite understand your question.